# How to call button click function in ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx, aspx-user-control

I am trying to add a button to my `ascx` page and do some functionalities. But the button `OnClick` not firing. So, please advise me on how to access the button click method. Thank you

ascx page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEncryptNIN" runat="server" Text="Encrypt" OnClick="btnEncryptNIN_Click"/>
```

ascx.cs:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("printreportingchart.aspx"))
            {
                lblEmpNumber.Style.Add("display", "none");
                lblEmpNumber1.Style.Add("display", "none");
                //miniProfile.InnerText = "";

            }
                
        }          
        protected void btnEncryptNIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string name = "s";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `Click` event is not wired up to the control `btnEncryptNIN` server control. There are a couple of ways to solve this. You can add `AutoEventWireup="true"` as an additional attribute to the `<%@ Control %>` on the first line of the ascx file.
OR you can add the line `btnEncryptNIN.Click += BtnEncryptNIN_Click;` into the Page_Load method in the ascx.cs code behind file

Comment: I did these two changes. But still not firing code behind function. Do I need to change something on my main aspx page?

Comment: only one or the other would be added. Recommend just adding the `AutoEventWireup="true"` .. can you please post the full `<% Control ... %>` line from the ascx as well as the full namespace and class name from the code behind file? The Control needs to point to the right cs file and Inherit from the right class...